# Currency filter in Angular shows me a blank space even though syntax is correct. Can anyone help me out?

Tags: html, angularjs

Okay, I don't know what's happening but the currency filter is not working in angular. It just shows me a blank space. Also, I have just started learning Angular. It would be great if anyone could help me out

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>AngularJS</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="">
        Currency: <input type="text" ng-model="price"> <br>
        {{'Welcome' + price| currency}}
        <script>

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe ` {{'Welcome' + (price| currency)}}`

Comment: Oh my bad! The Welcome should've been outside. Thanks!

Comment: @Austaras please add that as an answer so that OP can choose it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
{{'Welcome' + (price| currency)}}
```

as angular has low priority level